# Encontrar duplicado en columna de una tabla mysql desde Java

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy deseando encontrar item duplicado, que obtengo la frase de un **jtextfield(ean)**.

La tabla de mysql, *se llama* ***stock*** y *la columna se llama* ***ean***, la intensión es, si encuentra un duplicado en esta columna:

Que muestre el ***id*** que se encuentra en la columna **id** de la misma tabla ***(stock)***. y un mensaje que lo agrego con System.out.println("Encontre algo repetido")

```
    void buscadorLab() {
    try {
        Statement ejecuto = pa.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ejecuto.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock WHERE ean LIKE '%"+ean.getText()+"%'");
        if (rs.next() == true) {
                System.out.println("Encontre algo repetido = "+rs.getString(1));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("SOS GATO = " + rs.next());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR MYSQL = " + ex);
    }
}
```

El problema es que mi código me da todo false. Es como si tampoco estaría buscando.

Pregunta: **Es posible en el caso de encontrar un duplicado, obtener el id de ese item que se encontró?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion `count(*)` siempre va devolver un registro ya sea 0 o mayor, por eso el `rs.next()` siempre será `true`, debes evaluar el contenido de esta forma

```js
//si es mayor a 1 es por que hay repetidos segun el Like
if(rs.next() && rs.getInt(1) > 1){
  System.out.println("Encontre algo repetido = "+rs.getString(1));
}
```

Con respecto a la pregunta de obtener el **id** deberías tener una forma de saber cual seria el repetido, por lo general seria el ultimo registrado en tu tabla.
Lo mejor seria que esa lógica lo pases a código java para no subir la complejidad en el sql query yo lo haria de esta forma.

sql: `SELECT id FROM stock WHERE ean LIKE '%"+ean.getText()+"% order by id desc'`

**Ojo** que este query es suponiendo que el **id** sea correlativo y entero. Si tienes otra columna de control por ejemplo **fecha de registro** se debería ordenar por esa columna.

Java:

```js
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
wile(rs.next()){

  ids.add(rs.getInt(1));

}

if(ids.size() > 1){
  Integer idDuplicado = ids.get(0);
  System.out.println(String.format("El id duplicado es: %s", idDuplicado));
}
```

si te preocupa la cantidad de registros que puedan venir en el query puedes añadirle  `limit 2` con eso te aseguras que el query traiga al id duplicado

Comment: Hola Polexter, excelente muchas gracias me re sirvio lo que planteaste, me gustaria consultarte lo siguiente: Con tu arreglo de codigo, he logrado filtrar el resultado correctamente, pero el problema que estoy viendo es el siguiente.
En la tabla ponele que cargue un valor 1 y otro que es 1000, pero si yo busco 10 me dice que hay una coincidencia. como podria hacer que busque especificamente el dato que estoy ingresando y no uno parecido? se entiende? disculpa la molestia, y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Si vas a usar una búsqueda exacta entonces no uses el `like` sería `"select... where  ean = " + 10 + " order by ..."`